# Reflections on glass over transparent background disappear in the final render

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, transparency, color-management

[image: thanks.]
Ok, so I have this problem, in the first image you have the "final" render, here the glass from the windows doesn´t reflect the light that comes from behind the camera, something that you can see appearing in the "preview" one (which is the one on the right side). If I adjust the gamma in color management, reflections start to appear, but colors start to change too!. Any idea of what could be happening? thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your image, so don't try to fix it.

The issue is that the render viewer in blender is broken: the viewer won't show the pixels that are both luminous and fully transparent (alpha zero, RGB not zero) from an image with associated alpha (like the reflection on a window that have no occlusion but are only luminous).

Read: [How do I get the Glare node to output transparent instead of Black background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824) and: [Render Halo material with tranparent background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/67792/1853)

View your render As RGB (without alpha channel) and you will see that your information is there.

[image]

Or just composite an image over a background using alpha over.

If you are planing to do the final composite in an app that is not blender, make sure that you save as OpenEXR, to keep the integrity of your image.

Comment: Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/glow-effect-invisible-on-transparent-background/44137#44137

Comment: Thanks. You mean something like this on using alpha over?  : https://i.stack.imgur.com/wwyFp.png
I did save the file as EXR, a few minutes ago, but when I opened it with photoshop I don´t have the alpha channel anymore, it´s all gray, does that have to do with Photoshop or am I saving wrong the EXR?

Comment: Alpha Over: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiWXQ.png Read also: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/compositing/types/color/alpha_over.html?highlight=alpha%20over

Comment: Photoshop doesn't handle EXRs correctly. Try Krita, Affinity Photo or any compositing app.