# Render image becomes tranparent with more samples applied

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I was trying to create some bubbles. Everything was OK in render preview, but render result becomes completely transparent image.
[image]

Here you can see render preview. I use HDRi lighting and film transperant. 
First sample in render process shows a bit of "envelope" of each bulb.
[image]

Here you can see render at 2-3 samples and it's almost invisible.
[image]

here is a gif when render runs...
[image]

Here is my node setup. I can upload my .blend file if you help me how to do this:)
Yes, bubbles are visible, but it brings black background and some bugs. [image]

And the most interesting thing i found when i tried to save this image with black background without alpha.
[image]
THIS is the saved rendered image from previous screen!

Here is the comparison between rendered image and render preview at 1 sample.
[image]
And at 2 samples.
[image]

Comment: Is this possible to fix camera or rendering setting to get rid of the problem??? I don't really want to change my node setup because i like how it looks....

Comment: Are bubbles visible if you put channels of the image in UV Image editor to RGB without Alpha? (buttons to the right from the Image selector).

Comment: I don't see how 'more samples' makes the image disappear if you are using the same amount of samples for the preview and the final render?

Comment: Most likely there is nothing wrong with your file. This is an issue with the viewer. Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/56950/transparent-image-different-in-viewport-than-render/56986#56986 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87837/reflections-on-glass-over-transparent-background-disappear-in-the-final-render/87841#87841

Comment: Yes bro, this is the save problem. I can see my bubbles if i use alpha over node with black background.... Thank you.