# Fire and smoke to transparent in final render

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, compositing-nodes

I'm having a hard time rendering a fire and smoke simulation. I wanted to  record a animation and get the .pngs wiht alpha channel, but in the final render the objects in my case a meteor is transparent. 
My goal is to achieve a animation file that works like an rgba.

How do achieve the correct results ?

I tried rendering .png looks transparent
I tried composition nodes and with a blue and black background and it looks awful.
Ill tried rendering .png and converting into .MOV with png rgba format and it looks like the final render , transparent thing and also I went to Adobe after effects and followed this steps ---> https://www.rocketstock.com/blog/quickly-keying-out-black-backgrounds-in-after-effects/` and is gets some of the solution but is still 70% transparent.

I am ussing Blender 2.79 for windows 10 and using cycles.

Here is my example.

[image: my render]

Comment: You are probably doing nothing wrong, but the render viewer in blender cannot display your image correctly.  Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/87837/reflections-on-glass-over-transparent-background-disappear-in-the-final-render/87841#87841 view your image using RGB with no alpha (https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAoxU.png) or view it over a black background.

Comment: Avoid PNGs that format cannot represent associated alpha correctly. Render as EXRs

Comment: I read all those links and the conclusion is to export in EXRs, but how to i convert those EXRs in blender?

Even though i have a solution that i dont like at all but it works , that is export the animation to a quicktime with png RGBA, and go to After effects and link Levels and shift channels, like in this link, but it is not the 100% result i want. 
How do i pass to EXRs to quicktime or some format with the compositors?

Comment: ok, when i finish render in 2 hs ill tell you how it was! :D

Comment: Again...Don't save as PNG. Don't encode as video with a color background. Use EXR, that format will deal with associated alpha correctly. Bring the EXRs as image sequence in AfterDeffects and composite there. (or composite directly in blender).

Comment: But how to i composite those EXR in blender? my idea is to try it there :(

Comment: I'll be glad to help you but please ask this as a new question