# Glowing smoke material in cycles?

Tags: light, smoke-simulation

Wrapping up my Genji Ult project! I have the materials, the animations, and the particles down! The only thing I need to do now is to add the smoke like substance that comes off of the dragon! It definitely moves like smoke but it also is green and glows. I know how to make the smoke green, but how do I make it glow? I have tried an emission shader on both the surface and volume parts of the smoke domain's material output node! It winds up just showing the surface of the cube. [image] The smoke looking material coming off the dragon. I'm using blender cycles to render a smoke simulation and can color the smoke with the volume material settings but cannot make it this as an emission shader is used for surface not volume so it will just show the box as well.

Comment: Please add some reference images on how should it look.

Comment: Maybe you are experiencing a known limitation of the render viewer. It is possible that there is nothing wrong with what you are doing but the viewer is not displaying it properly. Please read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34002/glow-effect-invisible-on-transparent-background/44137#44137 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/42939/rendering-fire-animations-with-transparent-background/44148#44148 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67789/render-halo-material-with-tranparent-background/67792#67792

Comment: Also related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles