Problem with rendering animation with alpha channel and glare and using them in premiere pro
I'm currently working on some hologram animations for a short movie but I'm sort of new to Blender and therefore don't know a lot about the proper settings etc.
I've read through the posts that deal with the subject, but I've seen that all these posts were written years ago and are therefore based on other versions.
As far as I have seen, a lot has changed over the versions, so I don't really have an overview of what exactly has changed in the processes I need and what has not.
But of course I'll keep on checking it out.
Groundwork:

The assets I created are fairly simple shapes.
For these, I used Shade Nodes and Geometry Nodes to make materials etc. so that they resemble holograms (with transparency and everything).
Then I added glare in the compositing tab.

However, when I wanted to render the animations, problems arose.
According to various YouTube videos, the following settings must be made for rendering:

background transparency
file format: FFmpeg Video
Container QuickTime
Video Codec Quick Time Animation
for Color RGBA (I also want to have an alpha channel so that I can later integrate the animation into the film in Premiere Pro)

So I should get a .mov file with alpha channel and everything.
The problem, however, is that individual frames cannot be recognized or retrieved in Premiere.
And as soon as I select PNGs in the video codec, the glare etc. is gone and the colors are not displayed correctly.
Have I overlooked some setting in Blender, or is the problem with Premiere?
Of course I tried everything I could (e.g. all possible combinations of container and codec) but none of that worked. There must be a simple solution, right?
Thank you very much for your help, I would be grateful for any ideas or suggestions.
PS: If there is any information missing that is needed, just let me know, I am currently working on the solution permanently

Hello and welcome. Instead of Alpha, you could try to render with a black background and use a different layer /blend mode in Premier to add it to your scene (like multiply, add or screen)

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/173932/exr-color-difference-to-png https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/104642/partly-ignored-png-alpha/104658#104658 https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/260675/glare-alpha-not-saved-to-png-file

Hello and welcome. This question seems to have been asked before in multiple forms over time, and already has various answers but you never acknowledged any of them. We are not sure if you aware of the existing posts but none of the described techniques address your particular requisites, or you simply didn't do any research at all. Could you [edit] you post and clarify how your question differs from the suggested duplicates? Otherwise could you rephrase it to focus on a particular step you are stuck with?
