# how to render volume as image with alpha background?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, node-editor, transparency

I have a problem when I render this (using f12 ) node tree on my object in blender cycle I get nothing I tried to render another things and I get a results but with this node tree in my screen shot I get nothing 
in render mode 
[image: image description here]

when i click f12
[image]

my node tree and my transparent option 
[image]

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824:  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is due to the limitation of the image viewer (and the same problem occurs if you try and save your render as PNG) and is the same as that described in [Rendering fire animations with transparent background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/44148/29586). Change the viewer mode into RGB mode and you should see the results.

When rendering such an image (with combined alpha and emission) you should use a format that supports such images - such as EXR.

Comment: after i exported my image as exr and opend it in photo shop i only get a black scene but i can see my render in the f12 mode so where's the wrong now ?

Comment: Same problem with Photoshop. The thing is, your emission material has a colour and intensity while still being 100% transparent. A standard paint package cannot represent that and so the “colour” information is rendered invisible due to the conflict with those pixels being 100% transparent. Combining images in the conpositor can make use of the ‘emission’ element so it’s valid to be rendered that way, but you can’t easily visualise it without combining it with another image (So the emission overlays without obscuring). I’m sure someone else could explain this a whole lot better than I could.

Comment: read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67789/render-halo-material-with-tranparent-background/67792#67792