# Blender 2.8 volume over transparent background not showing in rendered image

Tags: rendering, shaders, lighting, volumetrics

I made this planet with a volumetric shader for the atmosphere

[image]

Left you see the atmosphere rendered in viewport mode
Right you see it just rendered out but now the volumetrics are missing

Any guesses?

Comment: Don't display your image with a transparent background. Look at the image in RGB. The viewer has been broken for a long time. 2.8 is not any better. Your information is likely there, but it cannot be displayed on the viewer. See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/32900/how-to-properly-render-smoke-on-a-transparent-background and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107848/how-to-render-volume-as-image-with-alpha-background

Comment: Read: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824

Comment: Thanks guys for the fast reply. This was the problem indeed. hope they ever fix it, thanks :)