# Transparent elements are different than viewport when saved as .png

Tags: rendering, transparency, render-layers

I am working on a project where I composed many layers with an transparent background. Now I rendered the whole thing and when I saved it the result looked different than the saved version
(The white background of the second image is alpha but opened with spacebar on mac)

[image: Render result]

[image: saved image]

Comment: Don't use PNG... the format cannot deal with emissive and transparent pixels. Read: [How do I get the glare to output transparent](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824)

Comment: And [render halo material with transparent background](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67789/render-halo-material-with-tranparent-background/67792#67792)

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/107848/how-to-render-volume-as-image-with-alpha-background?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles