# Smoke renders, but not fire in 2.79 Cycles. However, both are fine in rendered viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view, smoke-simulation, volumetrics

I have a scene with a rocket launching, so obviously fire is pretty important. However, after setting up the shaders and simulation, I can't get the fire to render. Strangely, the smoke is still rendered and the fire still emits light on the rocket, but doesn't appear below the rocket or shade the resulting smoke. Even stranger, the rendered viewport (ie 3D View set to Rendered) renders the scene perfectly. I'm at a complete loss. Here's a photo of the two views and my domain material: [image]

And a closer image of the domain material after I redid it (still didn't work): [image]

How can I get the fire to render? Thanks!

Comment: Could you add the .blend with https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/?

Comment: You are dealing with a known limitation of the viewer. Read also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/67789/render-halo-material-with-tranparent-background/67792#67792 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/57816/how-do-i-get-the-glare-node-to-output-transparent-instead-of-black-background/57824#57824 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/41574/render-semi-transparent-volume-with-cycles

Answer (score 1):

cegaton was right, it's a known issue with the viewport -- disabling Transparent under the Film tab and using a big plane behind my subject with a holdout shader let me render the flame correctly, then I used a lighten blend mode to composite it in Affinity Photo. Thanks, everyone!

Comment: Export as EXR and you will not loose the alpha channel